# How to convert yuy2 video samples to rgb samples?

Tags: c++, directshow

I know the formula to convert yuy2 to rgb as described in here: 
[Convert yuy2 to bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491649/how-to-convert-yuy2-to-a-bitmap-in-c)

My problem is that I don't know how to apply it in a directshow filter:

In directshow i have a buffer and a header but how do I convert these into rgb?
The formula is:

```
int C = luma - 16;
int D = cr - 128;
int E = cb - 128;
r = (298*C+409*E+128)/256;
g = (298*C-100*D-208*E+128)/256;
b = (298*C+516*D+128)/256;
```

How do i get these values and how do I write them into the output buffer?

This is how i copy the buffer at the moment:

```
long lSizeSample = sample->GetSize();
long lSizeOutSample = outsample->GetSize();
outsample->GetPointer(&newBuffer);
sample->GetPointer(&sampleBuffer);
memcpy((void *)newBuffer, (void *)sampleBuffer, lSizeSample);
```

So i just copy the buffer. But how do i modify it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `memcpy` you are expected to convert pixel by pixel, taking into consideration strides, planar/packed formatting etc. In most cases this needs to be well optimized, such as using SIMD, for decent performance.

You can do the math yourself, of course, but you can also have the conversion done for you by [Color Converter DSP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819079), if Vista+ is OK for you.

The DSP is available as DMO, or you can use [DMO Wrapper Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375519) and use it as a readily available DirectShow filter.