# What is the simplest RGB image format?

Tags: c, image, raster

I am working in C on a physics experiment, [Young's interference experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_interference_experiment) and I made a program who prints to `file` a huge bunch of pixels:

```
for (i=0; i < width*width; i++)
{
    fwrite(hue(raster_matrix[i]), 1, 3, file);
}
```

Where `hue`, when given a value [0..255], gives back a `char *` with 3 bytes, R,G,B.

I would like to put a minimal header in my image file in order to make this raw file a *valid* image file.

More concise, switching from:

```
offset
0000 : height * width : data } my data, 24bit RGB pixels
```

to:

```
offset
0000 : dword : magic        \
     : /* ?? */              \
0012 : dword : height         } Header <--> common image file
0016 : dword : width         /
     : /* ?? */             /
0040 : height * width : data  } my data, 24bit RGB pixels
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You probably want to use the [PPM format](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Write_a_PPM_file#C) which is what you're looking for: a minimal header followed by raw RGB.

Answer (score 14):

[TARGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truevision_TGA) (file name extension `.tga`) may be the simplest widely supported binary image file format if you don't use compression and don't use any of its extensions. It's even simpler than Windows `.bmp` files and is supported by ImageMagick and many paint programs. It has been my go-to format when I just need to output some pixels from a throwaway program.

Here's a minimal C program to generate an image to standard output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { width = 550, height = 400 };

int main(void) {
  static unsigned char pixels[width * height * 3];
  static unsigned char tga[18];
  unsigned char *p;
  size_t x, y;

  p = pixels;
  for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      *p++ = 255 * ((float)y / height);
      *p++ = 255 * ((float)x / width);
      *p++ = 255 * ((float)y / height);
    }
  }
  tga[2] = 2;
  tga[12] = 255 & width;
  tga[13] = 255 & (width >> 8);
  tga[14] = 255 & height;
  tga[15] = 255 & (height >> 8);
  tga[16] = 24;
  tga[17] = 32;
  return !((1 == fwrite(tga, sizeof(tga), 1, stdout)) &&
           (1 == fwrite(pixels, sizeof(pixels), 1, stdout)));
}
```

Comment: When do you initialise the bytes at offsets 0, 1, and 3 to 11 in the tga array? Is it guaranteed to be zeros thanks to the BSS linker section or something?

Comment: Good question. Indeed, global and static variables are guaranteed to be zero-initialized by C. If you got the array from `malloc()` or allocated it on the stack, you'd have to `memset()` it to zero manually (or use `calloc()` which does that by itself).

Answer (score 11):

The recently created [farbfeld](http://tools.suckless.org/farbfeld/) format is quite minimal, though there is not much software supporting it (at least so far).

```
Bytes                  │ Description
8                      │ "farbfeld" magic value
4                      │ 32-Bit BE unsigned integer (width)
4                      │ 32-Bit BE unsigned integer (height)
(2+2+2+2)*width*height │ 4*16-Bit BE unsigned integers [RGBA] / pixel, row-major
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a minimal example that writes your image file with a minimal PPM header.  Happily, I was able to get it to work with the exact for loop you've provided:

```
#include <math.h> // compile with gcc young.c -lm
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define width 256

int main(){
    int x, y, i; unsigned char raster_matrix[width*width], h[256][3];
    #define WAVE(x,y) sin(sqrt( (x)*(x)+(y)*(y) ) * 30.0 / width)
    #define hue(i) h[i]

    /* Setup nice hue palette */
    for (i = 0; i <= 85; i++){
        h[i][0] = h[i+85][1] = h[i+170][2] = (i <= 42)? 255:    40+(85-i)*5;
        h[i][1] = h[i+85][2] = h[i+170][0] = (i <= 42)? 40+i*5: 255;
        h[i][2] = h[i+85][0] = h[i+170][1] = 40;
    }

    /* Setup Young's Interference image */
    for (i = y = 0; y < width; y++) for (x = 0; x < width; x++)
        raster_matrix[i++] = 128 + 64*(WAVE(x,y) + WAVE(x,width-y));


    /* Open PPM File */
    FILE *file = fopen("young.ppm", "wb"); if (!file) return -1;

    /* Write PPM Header */
    fprintf(file, "P6 %d %d %d\n", width, width, 255); /* width, height, maxval */

    /* Write Image Data */
    for (i=0; i < width*width; i++)
        fwrite(hue(raster_matrix[i]), 1, 3, file);

    /* Close PPM File */
    fclose(file);


    /* All done */
    return 0;
}
```

The header code is based on the specs at http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html.  For this image, the header is just a string of fifteen bytes: `"P6 256 256 255\n"`.