# What's the 3D structurally simplest file format?

Tags: c, 3d, data-visualization, file-format

From my computations, I've got a lot of raw bytes of data. I would like to view them not as an image, but as a 3D relatively-standard file. (c.f. previous question about PPM :[What is the simplest RGB image format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636311/what-is-the-simplest-rgb-image-format) )

I would like to put in a file some header and a bunch of `struct point`, and open this file with a standard 3d file viewer such as g3dviewer.

```
struct point {
    unsigned int x; // coordinates
    unsigned int y;
    unsigned int z;
    unsigned char r; // color
    unsigned char g;
    unsigned char b;
}
```

I've already looked at the .OBJ file format, but it forces me to translate each point in a text line describing a cubic vertex.

Does this simple 3D file format exist ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [PLY](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ply/) format is fairly simple.

```
ply
format ascii 1.0
comment object: vertex cloud
element vertex 8
property uint x
property uint y
property uint z
property uchar red                   { start of vertex color }
property uchar green
property uchar blue
end_header
0 0 0 255 0 0                         { start of vertex list }
0 0 1 255 0 0
0 1 1 255 0 0
0 1 0 255 0 0
[...]
```

In line 4, the number of vertices is defined.