# How to convert from bytes (1D) array to RGB array (2D) in Python 3.6? (NumPy or SciPy?)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, byte, pixel

I've been experimenting with binary files and the concept of bytes.  One task that I am stuck on is once I read a file in as bytes in integer form, I can't figure out how to convert it to its RGB tuple form?  For example, when I use `np.fromfile` I read the file in as bytes in a base 10 integer representation.  If I read the file with `scipy.misc.imread` it reads the file in as rgb tuples.

**How can I go from the output of `np.fromfile` vector representation, to the RGB pixel representation from `scipy.misc.imread`?**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc

path = "./Data/image.jpg"

# Read image as bytes
A = np.fromfile(path, dtype=np.uint8, count=-1) 
A.shape
#(54021,)
A.min(), A.max()
# (0, 255)
A
# array([255, 216, 255, ..., 100, 255, 217], dtype=uint8)

# Read image as RGB tuples
B = misc.imread(path)
B.shape
(480, 480, 3)
B.min(), B.max()
# (0, 255)
B
# array([[[ 28,  27,  23],
#         [ 15,  14,  10],
#         [ 14,  13,   9],
#         ..., 
#         [ 31,  26,  20],
#         [ 29,  24,  20],
#         [ 33,  28,  24]],
```

This is the test image I was using below: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHiNp.jpg

Answer (score 0):

[JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) is a compressed image format, therefore you cannot directly get the rgb bitmap from the file contents. You have to pass it through a decoder first. The `imread()` call does this when it loads the file, using the decoder provided by [PIL](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/).

If you want a simpler image file format that is easy to parse, take a look at the answer to this question: [What is the simplest RGB image format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636311/what-is-the-simplest-rgb-image-format)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the shape accordingly. The actual steps are as follows:

1) Read the image using scipy's `misc.imread()`.
2) Create a raw file using the image array from step-1
3) Now, use `np.fromfile` for creating actual image from raw file
4) Assign the shape information from `misc.imread`

Code Example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc

# Read image using `imread`
suza = misc.imread('suza.jpg') 
suza.shape
# (1005, 740, 3)

# create raw file
suza.tofile('suza.raw')

# image from raw file
suza_from_raw = np.fromfile('suza.raw', dtype=uint8)
suza_from_raw.shape
# (2231100, )

# Assign the same shape from `misc.imread`
suza_from_raw.shape = (1005, 740, 3)
```

Comment: What if you didn't load `suza` in through `misc.imread` and did not have the exact shape of `suza` and did not want to store as a raw file.  If you just had the vector `A`, could you use this method with `io.BytesIO` to get the RGB array?