# Writing images with an Arduino

Tags: c, image, arduino

I have an SD card, SD card shield, and Arduino Uno R3. I need to write an image onto the SD card. I would much rather prefer going from a raw array to JPEG/PNG/BMP/etc, rather than using the formats that are easy to write, but not really openable (PPM, PGM, etc).

Is the image writing function included in the Arduino standard libraries? If not, what library should I use? I've looked at `lodePNG`, but ran into weird errors (`vector is not a member of std`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take zero credit for this code as I pulled it from a thread on the Arduino forums (http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=112733.0).  It writes a .bmp file to an SD card.

Another discussion indicated that because of the compression algorithms associated with JPG and PNG files, the amount of code to make those work would be more difficult to fit on an Arduino, which makes sense in my head (http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=76376.0).

Hope this helps.  Definitely not an expert with Arduino - just tinkered a bit.

```
#include <SdFat.h>
#include <SdFatUtil.h>

/*
 WRITE BMP TO SD CARD
 Jeff Thompson
 Summer 2012

 TO USE MEGA:
 The SdFat library must be edited slightly to use a Mega - in line 87
 of SdFatConfig.h, change to:

   #define MEGA_SOFT_SPI 1

 (this uses pins 10-13 for writing to the card)

 Writes pixel data to an SD card, saved as a BMP file.  Lots of code
 via the following...

 BMP header and pixel format:
   http://stackoverflow.com/a/2654860

 SD save:
   http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php?topic=112733 (lots of thanks!)
 ... and the SdFat example files too

 www.jeffreythompson.org
 */

char name[] = "9px_0000.bmp";       // filename convention (will auto-increment)
const int w = 16;                   // image width in pixels
const int h = 9;                    // " height
const boolean debugPrint = true;    // print details of process over serial?

const int imgSize = w*h;
int px[w*h];                        // actual pixel data (grayscale - added programatically below)

SdFat sd;
SdFile file;
const uint8_t cardPin = 8;          // pin that the SD is connected to (d8 for SparkFun MicroSD shield)

void setup() {

  // iteratively create pixel data
  int increment = 256/(w*h);        // divide color range (0-255) by total # of px
  for (int i=0; i<imgSize; i++) {
    px[i] = i * increment;          // creates a gradient across pixels for testing
  }

  // SD setup
  Serial.begin(9600);
  if (!sd.init(SPI_FULL_SPEED, cardPin)) {
    sd.initErrorHalt();
    Serial.println("---");
  }

  // if name exists, create new filename
  for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
    name[4] = (i/1000)%10 + '0';    // thousands place
    name[5] = (i/100)%10 + '0';     // hundreds
    name[6] = (i/10)%10 + '0';      // tens
    name[7] = i%10 + '0';           // ones
    if (file.open(name, O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_WRITE)) {
      break;
    }
  }

  // set fileSize (used in bmp header)
  int rowSize = 4 * ((3*w + 3)/4);      // how many bytes in the row (used to create padding)
  int fileSize = 54 + h*rowSize;        // headers (54 bytes) + pixel data

  // create image data; heavily modified version via:
  // http://stackoverflow.com/a/2654860
  unsigned char *img = NULL;            // image data
  if (img) {                            // if there's already data in the array, clear it
    free(img);
  }
  img = (unsigned char *)malloc(3*imgSize);

  for (int y=0; y<h; y++) {
    for (int x=0; x<w; x++) {
      int colorVal = px[y*w + x];                        // classic formula for px listed in line
      img[(y*w + x)*3+0] = (unsigned char)(colorVal);    // R
      img[(y*w + x)*3+1] = (unsigned char)(colorVal);    // G
      img[(y*w + x)*3+2] = (unsigned char)(colorVal);    // B
      // padding (the 4th byte) will be added later as needed...
    }
  }

  // print px and img data for debugging
  if (debugPrint) {
    Serial.print("\nWriting \"");
    Serial.print(name);
    Serial.print("\" to file...\n");
    for (int i=0; i<imgSize; i++) {
      Serial.print(px[i]);
      Serial.print("  ");
    }
  }

  // create padding (based on the number of pixels in a row
  unsigned char bmpPad[rowSize - 3*w];
  for (int i=0; i<sizeof(bmpPad); i++) {         // fill with 0s
    bmpPad[i] = 0;
  }

  // create file headers (also taken from StackOverflow example)
  unsigned char bmpFileHeader[14] = {            // file header (always starts with BM!)
    'B','M', 0,0,0,0, 0,0, 0,0, 54,0,0,0   };
  unsigned char bmpInfoHeader[40] = {            // info about the file (size, etc)
    40,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 1,0, 24,0   };

  bmpFileHeader[ 2] = (unsigned char)(fileSize      );
  bmpFileHeader[ 3] = (unsigned char)(fileSize >>  8);
  bmpFileHeader[ 4] = (unsigned char)(fileSize >> 16);
  bmpFileHeader[ 5] = (unsigned char)(fileSize >> 24);

  bmpInfoHeader[ 4] = (unsigned char)(       w      );
  bmpInfoHeader[ 5] = (unsigned char)(       w >>  8);
  bmpInfoHeader[ 6] = (unsigned char)(       w >> 16);
  bmpInfoHeader[ 7] = (unsigned char)(       w >> 24);
  bmpInfoHeader[ 8] = (unsigned char)(       h      );
  bmpInfoHeader[ 9] = (unsigned char)(       h >>  8);
  bmpInfoHeader[10] = (unsigned char)(       h >> 16);
  bmpInfoHeader[11] = (unsigned char)(       h >> 24);

  // write the file (thanks forum!)
  file.write(bmpFileHeader, sizeof(bmpFileHeader));    // write file header
  file.write(bmpInfoHeader, sizeof(bmpInfoHeader));    // " info header

  for (int i=0; i<h; i++) {                            // iterate image array
    file.write(img+(w*(h-i-1)*3), 3*w);                // write px data
    file.write(bmpPad, (4-(w*3)%4)%4);                 // and padding as needed
  }
  file.close();                                        // close file when done writing

  if (debugPrint) {
    Serial.print("\n\n---\n");
  }
}

void loop() { }
```

Comment: The Arduino has limited memory (~4k), so it's hard to hold the whole image in memory, but it write the image to the SD card fine. Is that right or wrong? I don't think there's some limit on writing to the SD card and memory.

Comment: So then you could write a PNG/JPEG, since you don't have to hold the whole image in memory, correct?

Comment: Correct, but the algorithms for encoding a PNG or JPEG are complex enough that it would be more difficult (but almost certainly not impossible, esp. with something like a mega) to get all of the code required to keep the encoding program plus the pieces of the image being encoded in memory.  If you look here, you see that encoding and writing a JPEG file is far more complex than BMP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Encoding. It's a similar story for PNG: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Technical_details  If you can do it, more power to you!

Comment: I've played with this code some more, and it always writes a 4x2 image, even if I pass in other values. I wrote a writeToBMPImage function, available on GitHub: https://github.com/scottsievert/IRcamera/blob/master/IRcamera.ino (available at line 119).

Comment: And I debugged my function more, and found out two things: you can't (I think) open files that are already open, and you can't have filenames longer than 8 characters, with a 3 character extension. This may be because I'm using the SD.h library, not SdFat (although I tried).

Comment: The SD.h library uses the primitive 8.3 naming convention thats why 8 characters max for file names and then the rest of the 3 after . for extension, its a legacy DOS based naming convention, I haven't tried with sdFat