# How to write this new char** to .bmp file?

Tags: c++, graphics, bitmap

How to convert `char**` to `bitmap` ?
I have image `width x height` and matrix of chars `3 * width x height` ( every pixel is represented like `triplet of char red, char green, char blue`). I filled this matrix from another loaded bitmap (I need just smaller rectangle of original bitmap so I filled in `char**/matrix`).
How to write this new `char**` to `.bmp` file ?
I tried like 
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/12848/

but it has strange behavior.

Comment: What OS are you running on? There are usually libraries you can use to save data as an image, but without more information it's hard to give you any advice.

Comment: Show us the code you have and we can help.

Comment: This gives a good overview of how the file needs to be formatted: http://tipsandtricks.runicsoft.com/Cpp/BitmapTutorial.html  What usually trips people up is the need to pad each line of pixels to a multiple of 4 bytes.

Comment: You shouldn't write your own code to output a .bmp file. Unless your purpose is just to learn how file formats work, you should use one of the libraries supplied by your OS or an Open Source library or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

A few possible directions:

1. Use Microsoft APIs: [CImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwea7by5%28VS.80%29.aspx) or CBitmap
2. Use existing library: http://code.google.com/p/libbmp/ or http://easybmp.sourceforge.net/ or http://sourceforge.net/projects/cimg/ or http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/bmp_io/bmp_io.html or ImageMagick (many more)
3. Don't use library, start here: [Writing BMP image in pure c/c++ without other libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654480/writing-bmp-image-in-pure-c-c-without-other-libraries)