# saving image buffer to file on android

Tags: android, c++, image, qt

I have an image buffer that I want to save to `bmp` file.

The code itself is `C++` & app running on `android` using `Qt`.

Is there any basic function or open source library that I can use to save the buffer on the device ?

except `FreeImage`, I have some issues with this library in android.

Answer (score 0):

Use QPixmap's save

```
QPixmap mypixmap;
mypixmap.save("filename", "BMP");
```

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#save

Comment: but the saving code should be in the C++ scope, not the app itself.

Comment: unless this lib supported c++ also?

Comment: It's part of the Qt API framework. It supports the main formats, JPG, PNG, BMP and GIF...

Comment: so it's not help me sir.. I need c++ code that save the image

Comment: You said you're using Qt, so the obvious choice was to use Qt's built in functionality. If you said you didn't want to use Qt's API, then I could've pointed to here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654480/writing-bmp-image-in-pure-c-c-without-other-libraries