# how to generate bitmap header data then write into a file using c++

Tags: c++, image, bitmap

I want to create a bitmap file header without any library. this is data of my image:

```
width = 3px;
height = 10px;
bits_per_pixle = 24;
```

How can i generate `54 bytes` data for it's header then write into a file? I have a lot of problems with this. I don't know How to write data into file in hex. i dont know how to write size of file in 4 bytes , etc.. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int w = 3;
    int h = 10;
    int bits_per_pixle = 24;
    ofstream des("file.bmp", ios::binary);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doing anything 'without any library' is difficult as much of C++ is in libraries (including ofstream for instance). Could you clarify which libraries you are and aren't allowed to use. For instance how about Windows libraries?

Comment: To write the data 'in hex' (really you mean 'as binary', 'in hex' doesn't make any sense) use the `ostream::write` method.

Comment: Really all you need to do is fill out your 54 byte data structure and then make one call to `ostream::write` to write your data to a file.

Comment: @john i am allowed to use ofstream etc... but I should not use a an extra library to work with bitmap files.

Comment: This might be interesting: [SO: Create image from unsigned char buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56054487/7478597). I did this for a question tagged [tag:C] but it surely works in C++ as well (with small modifications, may be).

Answer (score 0):

Use this structure:
[BITMAPINFOHEADER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd183376(v%3Dvs.85))

```
typedef struct tagBITMAPINFOHEADER {
  DWORD biSize;
  LONG  biWidth;
  LONG  biHeight;
  WORD  biPlanes;
  WORD  biBitCount;
  DWORD biCompression;
  DWORD biSizeImage;
  LONG  biXPelsPerMeter;
  LONG  biYPelsPerMeter;
  DWORD biClrUsed;
  DWORD biClrImportant;
} BITMAPINFOHEADER, *PBITMAPINFOHEADER;
```

Comment: Note, LONG is 4-byte signed, DWORD is 4-byte unsigned, WORD is 2-byte unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a version of the function for you. I tested it, it works successfully.

The function `createRawBitmap24()` creates a bitmap image without compression with 24 bits per pixel:

```
struct Color24
{
    uint8_t red;
    uint8_t green;
    uint8_t blue;
};
typedef std::vector<std::vector<Color24>> Image24;
bool check(const Image24 & img)
{
    // check the shape
    bool valid(!img.empty());
    if(valid)
    {
        size_t line_size(img[0].size());
        for(size_t i = 1; valid && (i < img.size()); ++i)
        {
            if(img.at(i).size() != line_size)
                valid = false;
        }
    }
    else
        valid = false;
    return valid;
}
bool createRawBitmap24(const std::string & file_path, const Image24 & img)
{
    bool success(false);

    if(check(img))
    {
        // ----- create the image in bmp format -----

        // find the padding size
        uint8_t padding_size(0);
        size_t n = img[0].size()*3;
        while(((n+padding_size) % 4) != 0)
            ++padding_size;

        // build the raw content
        const uint32_t ris = static_cast<uint32_t>(img.size()*(img[0].size()*3 + padding_size)); // raw image size
        uint8_t * raw_content = new uint8_t[ris];

        size_t cursor(0);
        for(int i = static_cast<int>(img.size()-1); i >= 0; --i) // read lines in reverse order
        {
            for(const Color24 & pixel : img.at(static_cast<size_t>(i)))
            {
                raw_content[cursor++] = pixel.blue;
                raw_content[cursor++] = pixel.green;
                raw_content[cursor++] = pixel.red;
            }
            for(size_t j = 0; j < padding_size; ++j)
            {
                raw_content[cursor++] = 0xFF;
            }
        }

        // build the header
        const uint32_t hs(54); // header size
        const uint32_t fs = (hs + ris); // file size
        const uint32_t width = static_cast<uint32_t>(img[0].size()); // image width (without padding)
        const uint32_t height = static_cast<uint32_t>(img.size()); // image height (without padding)
        const uint32_t reso(2835); // resolution, ~72 DPI

        const uint8_t header[hs] = {
            'B', 'M',
            static_cast<uint8_t>(fs & 0xFF), static_cast<uint8_t>((fs >> 8) & 0xFF), static_cast<uint8_t>((fs >> 16) & 0xFF), static_cast<uint8_t>((fs >> 24) & 0xFF),
            0, 0,
            0, 0,
            static_cast<uint8_t>(hs & 0xFF), static_cast<uint8_t>((hs >> 8) & 0xFF), static_cast<uint8_t>((hs >> 16) & 0xFF), static_cast<uint8_t>((hs >> 24) & 0xFF),
            40, 0, 0, 0,
            static_cast<uint8_t>(width & 0xFF), static_cast<uint8_t>((width >> 8) & 0xFF), static_cast<uint8_t>((width >> 16) & 0xFF), static_cast<uint8_t>((width >> 24) & 0xFF),
            static_cast<uint8_t>(height & 0xFF), static_cast<uint8_t>((height >> 8) & 0xFF), static_cast<uint8_t>((height >> 16) & 0xFF), static_cast<uint8_t>((height >> 24) & 0xFF),
            1, 0,
            24, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            static_cast<uint8_t>(ris & 0xFF), static_cast<uint8_t>((ris >> 8) & 0xFF), static_cast<uint8_t>((ris >> 16) & 0xFF), static_cast<uint8_t>((ris >> 24) & 0xFF),
            static_cast<uint8_t>(reso & 0xFF), static_cast<uint8_t>((reso >> 8) & 0xFF), static_cast<uint8_t>((reso >> 16) & 0xFF), static_cast<uint8_t>((reso >> 24) & 0xFF),
            static_cast<uint8_t>(reso & 0xFF), static_cast<uint8_t>((reso >> 8) & 0xFF), static_cast<uint8_t>((reso >> 16) & 0xFF), static_cast<uint8_t>((reso >> 24) & 0xFF),
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0
        };

        // ----- Write the content in the file -----
        std::ofstream out_s(file_path, std::ofstream::binary);
        if(out_s)
        {
            for(size_t i = 0; i < hs; ++i)
                out_s << header[i];
            for(size_t i = 0; i < ris; ++i)
                out_s << raw_content[i];

            out_s.close();
            success = true;
        }
        delete [] raw_content;
    }
    return success;
}
```

To use it, you just have to call the function `createRawBitmap24()` and give as arguments the file path and the `Image24` to create.
As you can see, `Image24` is a typedef of `std::vector<std::vector<Color24>>`.
`Color24` is the structure I created to handle RGB colors.

The types I used (`uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, ...) are to make it more readable. When the bitmap specification said 1, 2 or 4 bytes are needed for a header field, I used the corresponding explicit type. But if these types are not defined in your platform, you can replace them by `unsigned char`, `unsigned short` and `unsigned int` (just check with `sizeof()` if the sizes are the same to 1, 2 and 4). But if you can include cstdint, it should be fine.

Of course, you can adapt the function for your needs.

I hope it will help you.